# WCF with XmlSerializer: namespace collision when returning generic contracts

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces, wcf-serialization

#### The background

I'm developing a REST API for a C#.NET web application using WCF. I configured it to use the XmlSerializer rather than its default DataContractSerializer, for greater control over the XML format. I created a generic `ResponseContract<TResponse, TErrorCode>` data contract, which wraps the response with `<Api>` and `<Response>` for generic data like request status, error messages, and namespaces. An example method:

> `ResponseContract<ItemListContract, ItemListErrorCode> GetItemList(...)`

An example response from the above method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Api xmlns="http://example.com/api/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Response Status="OKAY" ErrorCode="OKAY" ErrorText="">
      <Data Template="ItemList">
         <Pages Template="Pagination" Size="10" Index="1" Count="13" Items="126" />
         <Items>
            <Item example="..." />
            <Item example="..." />
            <Item example="..." />
        </Items>
      </Data>
   </Response>
</Api>
```

#### The problem

This works very well for services whose methods all have the same generic `ResponseContract` types. WCF or `XmlSerializer` expects each contract to have a unique name within its namespace, but the service is now returning a generic contract with different types having the same XML root name:

```
ResponseContract<ItemListContract, ItemListErrorCode> GetItemList(...)
ResponseContract<ItemContract, ItemErrorCode> GetItem(...)
```

With the resulting exception:

```
The top XML element 'Api' from namespace 'http://example.com/api/' references distinct types Company.Product.ApiServer.Contracts.ResponseContract`2[Company.Product.ApiServer.Contracts.Items.ItemListContract,Company.Product.ApiServer.Interfaces.Items.ItemListErrorCode] and Company.Product.ApiServer.Contracts.ResponseContract`2[Company.Product.ApiServer.Contracts.Items.ItemContract,Company.Product.ApiServer.Items.ItemErrorCode]. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.
```

The service must allow different return types. This is difficult to achieve because the `ResponseContract<TResponse, TErrorCode>` (which sets the name & namespace) is generic and returned by all API methods. I also need to maintain [WSDL metadata](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) integrity, which means no dynamic changes using reflection.

#### Attempted solutions

1. Changing the XML attributes declaratively is not possible, since the `<Api>` root element and its attributes are completely generic (in `ResponseContract`).
2. Changing the attribute namespace at runtime using reflection (eg, 'http://example.com/api/Items/GetItemList') has no effect. It's possible to *get* attributes, but changes to them have no effect. This would break WSDL anyway.
3. When implementing IXmlSerializable, the writer is already positioned after the `<Api>` start tag when `WriteXml()` is invoked. It's only possible to override the serialization of `<Api>`'s child nodes, which cause no problem anyway. This wouldn't work anyway, since the exception is thrown before the `IXmlSerializable` methods are called.
4. Concatenating the constant namespace with `typeof()` or similar to make it unique doesn't work, because the namespace must be a constant.
5. The default `DataContractSerializer` can insert type names into the name (like `<ApiOfIdeaList>`), but `DataContractSerializer`'s output is bloated and unreadable and lacks attributes, which is not feasible for the external reusers.
6. Extending `XmlRootAttribute` to generate the namespace differently. Unfortunately there is no type information available when it's invoked, only the generic `ResponseContract` data. It's possible to generate a random namespace to circumvent the problem, but dynamically changing the schema breaks the WSDL metadata.
7. Making `ResponseContract` a base class instead of a wrapper contract should work, but would result in a lot of duplicated generic data. For example, `<Pages>` and `<Item>` in the example above are also contracts, which would have their own equivalent `<Api>` and `<Response>` elements.

#### Conclusion

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the tumbleweed badge for this one!

I abandoned the described approach because I couldn't find a viable solution. Instead, every contract inherits a nullable `QueryStatus<TErrorCode>` property from the generic `BaseContract<TContract, TErrorCode>`. This property is populated automatically for the main contract, and `null` for subcontracts.